# PHP WooCommerce Simple Check (if contains) $product inside custom tab element?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been bouncing my head of a brick wall trying to hide a custom tab depending on grouped_products->child_products attributes so I was wondering is there a simple way to check if my custom tab contains a $product element? if it does not contain a $product then hide the tab?

I can't hide the tab if empty as my custom PHP file (grouped.php) spits out the table even if there is no content (products) with in it.

Currently the function I'm using is not working and the tab shows either way for some reason. This function is supposed to check the child products of the group and then determine if an attribute is present 'PAYG' if so return the custom tab if not do not return the custom tab but it is showing on pages it's not supposed to be at the minute so it is not working.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'woo_simfree_product_tab' );

function woo_simfree_product_tab( $tabs ) {

global $post;
if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
$product = get_product( $post->ID );

    if ($product->is_type( 'grouped' )) {
            $PAYG = false;

            foreach ($product->get_children() as $child_id) {
                $child = get_product($child_id);
                $attr = $child->get_attribute('contract-type');
                    if ($attr == 'PAYG') {
                        $PAYG = true;
                    }
            }

            if ($PAYG = true) {
                $tabs['simfree-plans'] = array( 'title' => __( 'SIM Free', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 20, 'callback' => 'woo_simfree_product_tab_content' );
            } else {
                return $tabs;
            }

    } else {
        return $tabs;
    }

}
}
```

Is there anyway to just check weather the tab contains a $grouped_product that would be so much easier to code then if there is no product there just hide the tab.

My tab contents are calling a custom grouped.php..

```
// Function below creates an add to cart function which fetches a custom template from child theme. To add more custom add to cart templates just copy and change the path.

function woocommerce_grouped_simfree() {
    global $product;
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/grouped-simfree.php', array(
        'grouped_product'    => $product,
        'grouped_products'   => $product->get_children(),
        'quantites_required' => false
    ) );
}

// Tab content for custom tab

function woo_simfree_product_tab_content() {
    woocommerce_grouped_simfree();
}
```

Please help thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function woo_simfree_product_tab( $tabs ) {

    global $post;
    $PAYG = false;

    if (function_exists( 'get_product' )) {
        $product = get_product( $post->ID );

        if ($product->is_type( 'grouped' )) {
            foreach ($product->get_children() as $child_id) {
                $child = get_product($child_id);
                $attr = $child->get_attribute('contract-type');
                if ($attr == 'PAYG') {
                    $PAYG = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($PAYG == true) {
        $tabs['simfree-plans'] = array( 'title' => __( 'SIM Free', 'woocommerce' ), 'priority' => 20, 'callback' => 'woo_simfree_product_tab_content' );
    }

    return $tabs;
}
```

also, make sure `$attr = $child->get_attribute('contract-type');` is getting the right value... try checking it.

Comment: $attr is definatly fetching the correct attribute as I run this inside the tab... `global $post;

 $product = get_product( $post->ID );

foreach ($product->get_children() as $child_id) {
                $child = get_product($child_id);
                $attr = $child->get_attribute('contract-type');
                echo 'attr = '.$attr.'</br>';
                }` to loop through and echo every $attr in the loop.

Comment: and the result was `attr = PAYG
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM
attr = PAYM`

Comment: dude your function works I just had to change your if ($PAYG = true) to == as = is setting it not checking it thanks man

Comment: yeah sorry.. it was a typo